# MvcSiteMapProvider not picking up roles for menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, roles, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVC5, windows authentication, structuremap DI and custom role provider.

MvcSiteMapProvider for MVC5 is not picking up the roles to show menu based on user role. When security trimming is enabled it shows only menu items which do not have any roles attribute defined.

I have ActionFilterAttribute implemented and used on controller for authorization. Controller correctly redirects the user to unauthorized page based on roles but menu is not picking the role attributes to hide the menu.

Custom RoleProvider has implementation for GetRolesForUser and GetUsersInRole.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Also want to know where to look for roles attributes in SiteMapNodeModel. I am thinking of customizing to look for permission in the HtmlHelper while building the menu.

Note: Same implementation is working fine in MVC4. Once upgraded to MVC5 and it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: I am generating the menu like in this post and want to check within foreach for permission  @foreach (SiteMapNodeModel node in nodeList)
https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/asp-net-mvc-5-menu-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-3-navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MvcSiteMapProvider for MVC5 is not picking up the roles to show menu based on user role. When security trimming is enabled it shows only menu items which do not have any roles attribute defined.

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming#interoperability-with-aspnet), the roles attribute is not for use with MVC. It is for interop with ASP.NET pages.

It only functions when the security framework implements `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` as Membership and Identity do.

> I have ActionFilterAttribute implemented and used on controller for authorization. Controller correctly redirects the user to unauthorized page based on roles but menu is not picking the role attributes to hide the menu.

This is most likely your issue. Security trimming only looks for `AuthorizeAttribute` and subclasses of `AuthorizeAttribute`. If you have subclassed `ActionFilterAttribute`, it will not be used to hide links from navigation.

Of course, for the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` to work, you need to implement `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` or use one of the pre-built security frameworks that does the same.

Alternatively, you could build your own `IAclModule` or `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` if you have completely custom security.

> Also want to know where to look for roles attributes in SiteMapNodeModel. I am thinking of customizing to look for permission in the HtmlHelper while building the menu.

You would not need to look for roles from the `SiteMapNodeModel`. Instead, you should get the roles from the current context and make the changes to the menu templates in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` accordingly.

If you are using a framework that supports `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`, you could just use:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("SomeRole"))
{
    ...
}
```

Also see the following:

- [ASP.NET MVC 5 Customise Bootstrap navbar based on User Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305497/asp-net-mvc-5-customise-bootstrap-navbar-based-on-user-role)
- [Implementing Role Based Menu in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://techbrij.com/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc)

If you want to get the current roles that are configured for an action method, you can build an extension method to read the roles from the current `AuthorizeAttribute`. Again, the `roles` attribute is only for interoperability with ASP.NET and should not be used for pure MVC, since it means you need to duplicate your roles on `AuthorizeAttribute` anyway.

```
public static class ControllerContextExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Roles(this ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var controllerType = controllerContext.Controller.GetType();
        var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);
        var actionName = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
        var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

        var authorizeAttribute = FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor)
            .Where(f => typeof(AuthorizeAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(f.Instance.GetType()))
            .Select(f => f.Instance as AuthorizeAttribute).FirstOrDefault();

        string[] roles = { };
        if (authorizeAttribute != null && authorizeAttribute.Roles.Length > 0)
        {
            roles = Array.ConvertAll(authorizeAttribute.Roles.Split(','), r => r.Trim());
        }

        return roles;
    }
}
```

### Usage

In view:

```
{ var roles = this.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.Roles(); }
```

In controller:

```
var roles = this.ControllerContext.Roles();
```

### To get the roles from the `SiteMapNodeModel`:

```
    var siteMap = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current;
    var siteMapNode = siteMap.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(SiteMapNodeModel.Key);
    var roles = siteMapNode.Roles;
```

Comment: I was thinking of checking the roles while creating the menu. I want to know how to get the roles information from the Mvc.sitemap xml. I am looping the SitemapNodeModel list to create the menu but I cannot see roies anywhere. If  I rename the roles in xml to something else I can see it in attributes property of the node while creating the menu. I was hoping to get the list of roles defined in xml somehow. I do not have issues getting user permissions..

Comment: Thanks. Nice approach to read roles. I am not asking about the user roles. I am asking about the roles defined in Mvc.sitemap xml. I am creating the menu like below <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @foreach (SiteMapNodeModel node in nodeList)
                    {}
                                        </ul>

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. will try